# How to share data between two Windows Form in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#

M a beginner n want some help

I have 2 forms

1. Form1
2. Form2

**Form1** contains a label, textbox, button.

**Form2** contains a textbox only.

I want that when i click on the button in **Form1**, the text in **Textbox** **(Form1 textbox)** should pass to **Form2** and show it in the **textbox** of **Form2**.

Code For Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public String str;


    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
    public class global
    {
        public static String str;

    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        str = textBox1.Text;

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show();
    }
}
```

### Code for Form2.cs

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String str1 = Form1.global.str;
        textBox1.Text = str1;

    }
}
```

Comment: Create a Instance of Form2 in Form1buttonClick and Assign the the text From Form1 to Form2.text. Assumption: Classes and Fields are Public and you want to open Form2 from Form1 Button click.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: How do u show your both forms? can you post your code here?

Comment: Post your code and explain your problem a little bit more.

Comment: So, you want to pass value from one form to another form(form2) when form2 is loading?

Comment: The problem is that you have created the global class in form1 class.

Comment: i got d solution.. thnks everyone ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally thanks to all.
i got d solution by experimenting all ur ans...

code for Form2: in which data is to be passed

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public class global
    {
        public static String str;

    }


    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
   }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //String str1 = Form1.global.str;
        textBox1.Text = global.str;
    }
```

code for Form1: from where data is to be passed

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public String txtstr;


    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtstr = textBox1.Text;
        Form2.global.str = txtstr;

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another class in your project. Make all the members of that class static (So they can be called with the class name).

`public class global
{
    public static string strValue = "";
}`

Now on button click event assign textbox1.Text value to string variable in `global` class.

```
strValue = this.textbox1.Text;
```

Now you can access textbox1.Text value globally just by using static variable. In form 2 you can assign the value to other text box as

```
this.textbox2.Text = global.strValue;
```

Note: Here in the example, I assumed that textbox1 is on form1 ans textbox2 is on form2.

EDIT:
I have made changes in your code.
**Code For Form1.cs**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{      

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        global.str = textBox1.Text;

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show();
    }
}
public class global
{
    public static string str;

}
```

**Code for Form2.cs**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        textBox1.Text = global.str;    
    }
}
```

Comment: No need to do the global static variable at all - bad design practice and maintainability. Simply create an instance of form 2, have a public property there or a method in there which accepts the string parameter and that then assigns it to the textbox in form 2

Comment: Creating an instance of form2 will result in a call to InitializeComponents() which will create/ load all the components and controls of form2. Also, you can't directly access controls of one form in another form because they both run on different threads and you will get a crossthreadexception.

Comment: I don't agree with Ahmed - static variables are good ways to share data in .NET. Of course, assuming the OP is aware of race conditions and deadlocks.

Comment: Sorry ricky ..I tried a lot but the code doesn`t gave the desired output.

Comment: i put a breakpoint on the code line String str1 = Form1.global.str; 
this was in form2_load in Form2.cs. 
Here there was NULL value in str.

Comment: In form1, have you assigned the value to static variable? assign it as `global.strValue = textbox1.Text;`

Comment: @kayson - its best practice to not use static variables otherwise you will most likely be stepping over data and making everything static and global. think about encapsulation and relevance. It is also a discouraged practice from Microsoft. Rather than finding issues that can occur such as race conditions, it is going to take double the effort to fix it so why not make it right the first time round? It also logically makes no sense to store it in a static global variable, this also defeats encapsulation and true OO practices.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple take a look here it is fully work example two form formtest1(sender) formtest2(receiver) nothing esle:

```
Public Class Formtest1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Not IsNothing(Formtest2) Then
        Formtest2.TextBox1.Text = Me.TextBox1.Text
        If Formtest2.Visible = False Then
            Formtest2.Show()
        Else
            Formtest2.Focus()
        End If
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

here c# translate on the fly online ;)

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
public class Formtest1
{

private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((Formtest2 != null)) {
        Formtest2.TextBox1.Text = this.TextBox1.Text;
        if (Formtest2.Visible == false) {
            Formtest2.Show();
        } else {
            Formtest2.Focus();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Hope this help

Comment: have your seen the tag?

Comment: Hi Wulworine sorry your 'right i will update post with a copy in c#  lol i'm to tired today ......

Comment: but, it is better to create property for this instead of changing modifier of any control.

Comment: it depend on how do you want to achive your goal.There's a lot of way to make same stuff.If i need to pass a value i can use, variables, property, call properties of an object when it is visible and so on so forth.It depend on which way you want to reach your goal.Nothing else.Also you say "I need to pass a value from A to B" that's all and this is what done.

Comment: When i built a project i usually checking all the entities involved in it and if is need i create some custom class to reduce code redundancy and many other stuff.It depend from your final goal.If you need to do it in a single form and a particular value is not to be stored permanently you can do this also you can choose another way.

Comment: assigning whole control object as a public member is not a good habit.   You should assign only a part that you want to use. `Public Property FirstName As String Get Return txtFName.Text End Get Set(Value As String) txtFName.Text = Value End Set End Property`

Comment: I agree and I repeat he needs a simple example. We can talk about some particular stuff for hours but the question is : is somebody asking for a first approach to this issue? Yes No if yes just show it a simple basic code to achieve his goal. I saw more than one time that people asking and wait to have more complex code as per their initial questions.

Comment: So i think is better show basic code and then if they need more info we can help them showing the right suggestions base on their extended code. Question was 
**I want that when i click on the button in Form1, the text in Textbox (Form1 textbox) should pass to Form2 and show it in the textbox of Form2 ** and it is done it nothing else. :)